# What the meaning of "generic" in Colding-Minicozzi's paper "Generic mean curvature flow I; generic singularities"?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

What is the exact meaning of "generic" in Colding-Minicozzi's paper "Generic mean curvature flow I; generic singularities"? ([DOI link](https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2012.175.2.7), [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3788)) Is there a specific explanation somewhere? I did not find it in that paper. Does someone know a paper or a book having a expanation of it? Thanks.

Comment: It appears they are using it in the sense of general position.  i.e. a feature of a metric is "generic" if it also holds for all nearby metrics.

Answer (score 1):

I think most genericity in differential geometry is in the Baire category sense, i.e., a set is generic if it contains the intersection of a countable number of open dense subsets.

Thus the question is what topology they are using here. For the space of hypersurfaces, it usually means the $C^\infty$-topology, that is, locally they could be written as graphs and they converge in any $C^k$-norm.